# page.php doesn't show menu if I'm not login in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a problem, I'm trying to create a menu with php ( no WordPress theme support ). When I'm in a page and I'm login in, the menu shows correctly, but if I'm not loged in, the menu doesn't show (only a horizontal bar).

This is the code that I use in `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="pingback" href=" <?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" >
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>

<div class="container bg-white tsb-margin-2">

    <header class="tsb-margin-alt">

        <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 300px;">

            <a class="text-dark text-center" heef="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );?>" rel="home">

            <h3><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h3>

            </a>

        </div>

    </header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Home</a>
            </li>

            <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) : ?>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <?php if (current_user_can('moderator') || current_user_can('administrator')) : ?>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/test1/' ) ); ?>">Test </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="">Test </a>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-login.php?action=logout' ) ); ?>">Logout</a>
                </div>
                </li>

            <?php else : ?>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/login/' ) ); ?>">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/createa/' ) ); ?>">Create account</a>
                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (current_user_can('administrator')) : ?>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-admin/' ) ); ?>">Adminn</a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/contact/' ) ); ?>">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this one in `page.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="page-content">      
    <div class="wrapper">
                <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                  
                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                      
                        <div class="post-header">
                            <h1 class="entry-title" id="post_heading">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </h1>
                            <?php get_the_tags(); ?>
                            <p class = "post_date"><?php the_date('M-Y'); ?>  </p>
                        </div>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>                  
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                <div class="post"><h2><?php _e('Not Found', 'mytheme'); ?></h2></div>
                <?php endif; ?>     


    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Does someone know something about it?

EDIT:
IMG Login in: https://images2.imgbox.com/e8/a2/1ZebbGa5_o.png
IMG Logout : https://images2.imgbox.com/e2/3f/qLOfjK5O_o.png

Comment: looks like all works as expected. can you provide screenshots of what you have as logged in, and how it looks when you logged out?

Comment: Yes,
Logged in IMG: https://images2.imgbox.com/e8/a2/1ZebbGa5_o.png 
Logout IMG: https://images2.imgbox.com/e2/3f/qLOfjK5O_o.png

Comment: when you're logged out( the second image ), you're on the `/login/` page, which is not related to `page.php`. do you use any plugins/ templates related to login page? look at website, when you're logged out  on some other page( home/contact and etc. ), where loading the `page.php` file. also, you may want to look at [templates hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)